# Haskell StateT and ExceptT chain

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I am not very good haskell programer. I am tasked to write a compiler at my university and I have choosen haskell, as it is good tool for that purpose. I am using monads StateT and ExcepT, so I have types:

```
type Runner r s = StateT s (ExceptT LatteError IO) r
type RT r s = IO (Either LatteError (r, s))
```

I use it create walk a program tree and produce asm code and it works as I want. As main function for walking over tree I use

```
rProgram :: Program -> Runner [String] CompileState
```

and to unpack result I use function

```
runR program = runExceptT (runStateT (rProgram program) initialCompileState)
```

What I want to do not is to have some validators, like type check, ident existance check, and I know to write them. Lets tell I have

```
tcProgram :: Program -> Runner () TypeCheckState
ieProgram :: Program -> Runner () IdentExistanceState
```

I want to run them both in elegant way, and an failure is indicated by throwError. How to put many functions like them together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lens` has a [`zoom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#v:zoom) combinator which uses a lens to "zoom in" on a part of the state.

```
zoom :: Lens' s t -> State t a -> State s a
```

(As is usual in `lens`, the actual type of `zoom` is more complicated than that, but this is a simple way to think about it.)

So we have

```
zoom _1 . tcProgram :: Program -> Runner () (TypeCheckState, t)
zoom _2 . ieProgram :: Program -> Runner () (s, IdentExistenceState)
```

and so

```
liftA2 (>>) (zoom _1 . tcProgram) (zoom _2 . ieProgram) :: Program -> Runner () (TypeCheckState, IdentExistenceState)
```

Comment: Only to my consideration, how to replace liftA2, if I want to have like 5 runners?

Comment: @MichałPiotrStankiewicz Either write out the argument (`\p -> do { zoom _1 (tcProgram p) ; zoom _2 (tcProgram p) ; etc }`) or stick a [`ReaderT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html) in your monad transformer stack.